# how to update a sql database table based on the condition from another table in the same database

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update

I have a two tables in a database.

```
table_1(device_ID, date,voltage)

table_2(device_ID,device_status)
```

I am trying to create an event to execute every 5 minutes.

What I am trying to achieve is, select device_ID from table_1 if there is no new data over the last 10 minutes and update the table_2, that means set device_status to 0.

How do i pass conditions between two tables?

```
BEGIN 
  select device_ID from table_1 where date =  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 Minutes);                          

//here i will get device_IDs if there was a data within last 10 minutes. 

//but i need device_ID if there were no data. 

//how to update table_2 based on the above condition?

END
```

Comment: Why bother with table2 at all?

Comment: i am using table_2 for some other operations.

Comment: Why bother using table2 for some other operations?

Comment: what do you mean? I want to know the status of the device !!!

Comment: table1 tells us that - plus it's bang up-to-date (not on some 10 minute delay)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the results of your first query as a subquery to de-select rows (by using `NOT IN`) for the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE table2
SET device_status = 0
WHERE device_ID NOT IN (select device_ID 
                        from table_1 
                        where date >  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 Minutes))
```

Note I think you probably want `>`, not `=` in your `where` condition in the subquery.

Comment: why ´>´ but not ´=´

Comment: @sunny_old_days `=` will only give you devices which updated exactly 10 minutes ago. `>` will give you devices which updated *less than* 10 minutes ago.